# Write command for only saving the config to power memory

Tags: cisco, switch

I'm confused on what command to use on a cisco switch where if the power is unplugged from the switch, I lose the configuration I saved and it reverts back to the previous config. I've been researching through commands like write memory and copy running-config startup-config but they both state that it overwrites the start up config file meaning it's permanent? Is this correct? I want to test my new config when there's power but be able to revert back to the old config if I pull the power. What's the command for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not save your configuration. If you make changes, but do not write them to the startup configuration, then restarting the device through reload or power loss, you will lose the changes.

Comment: Would the changes be applied to the switch even if it's not saved?

Comment: Yes, changes made to a Cisco device take effect immediately, changing the running configuration, but they are not saved to the startup configuration unless you specifically do that.

Comment: Im trying to regenerate an rsa key for SSH but after I generate the key and look at the results through show crypto key mypubkey rsa it shows that nothing has changed.

Comment: The crypto stuff needs to be zeroized before you put new in. The device ships with crypto, and it will auto generate if you delete it and restart. There are some specific steps you need to follow to replace the crypto as it will regenerate.

Comment: Thanks, My new question is at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73712/ssh-key-generation

Answer (score 0):

*wr mem* and *copy run start* both replace the startup configuration. If you don't want to replace the startup config, (obviously) don't save to the startup config. *copy run somwhere-else*. There are many options for "somewhere-else".

The running configuration is what you're changing with *conf t*. Those changes do not persist if you don't take steps to save them.